# Reinforcing load bearing wall

Tags: walls, load-bearing

Pretty sure the box across the opening is a beam and the wall is load bearing. Want to remove these studs on this wall and the wall behind it to open up my living room to kitchen and create a bit of a counter if you will. about 4ft up from the ground and 4 ft from the doorway will still remain. I will keep the studs/post on the right side of the entry way.

My idea is to double stack 2x6s across the top of the opening and use a stud at either end to support it. Will this work?

[image]

Comment: To size your new 4' clear span opening, we need to know how much load this wall is supporting. Do you have any floors above this, or just roof? How far is it from this wall to the exterior door in this picture, and also how far is it from this wall to the exterior wall behind you that we can't see in this picture? Your location is also important (US state or country), so that we know if we need to add snow load to the roof, or other loads.

Comment: Also consider that 2x6 douglas fur (different species have different tensile strength) have a rough span of 6' but you'll still get deflection in it. This is all for dead load though. If you have live load then even double stacked 2x6 wouldn't be sufficient for 6'. For 4', maybe.

Comment: 2x6 is not suitable for load-bearing walls at any span over about 2'. The minimum is usually doubled 2x10, and that would be good only to about 5'. After that you're looking at doubled LVLs of 9" or taller, up to 14", depending. Bottom line is that this is a question for a local engineer, not us.

Comment: exterior door you can see is approx 10-12ft. Directly across (behind me) is my front door about the same distance. Only attic/crawl space above. I live i Michigan.

Comment: Im also wondering why I have a beam that ends where the studs start, if anyone can answer this. Though Im not positive it is a beam and not just 2x4s since I can't see it.

Comment: I would open up that drywall above the opening and see if you find a beam in there. You're going to be patching drywall anyway so other than making a bit of a mess you're not creating much more work.

Comment: Why would you expect a beam to continue into a load-bearing wall?

Comment: Voting to close. OP has jumped ship and we need details.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly dependent on design snow load.  2x6s work just fine with 40 PSF roof snow load on a lower strength species like hem fir.  2x8s  Go up to 80 PSF but double up on the 2x4s for bearing length.  Over that you should go 2x10s and eventually 4x4 supports.

This assumes a "normal" roof finish like shakes/shingles.  Drop the allowed snow load for things like concrete, clay, slate, etc.